# Month not correct when geting UTC month

Tags: javascript, datetime

I am following these instructions https://stackoverflow.com/a/15012173/3808307

but I really don't get it. Now it is June 4th in my time zone and in UTC

I am doing `timeRef.current = new Date()`

Then

```
console.log(timeRef.current.getUTCFullYear()) // returns 2020
console.log(timeRef.current.getUTCMonth()) // returns 5
```

Why is my month 5? How can I get YYYYMMDD-HHMMSS.milliseconds in UTC univocally?

I don't want to have errors when, for example, it's Feb 29th, like here [Javascript date - setting UTC month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55415476/javascript-date-setting-utc-month)

I need a precise way of converting

Thank you

Comment: Months are zero indexed so 5 is June. That's a strange format but you can get it by `new Date().toISOString().replace(/[^\d\.]/g,'').replace(/(^\d{8})/,'$1-')`, see [*How to format a JavaScript date*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date?r=SearchResults&s=1|1450.4192).

Comment: @RobG I think I am going to use this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you need!

```
var timeRef = new Date()

console.log(timeRef.getUTCFullYear()) // returns 2020

console.log(timeRef.getUTCMonth()+1) // returns 6
```

Answer (score 2):

The getUTCMonth() returns the month of the specified date according to universal time, as a zero-based value (where zero indicates the first month of the year)

Answer (score 1):

Month index starts from 0 with range 0-11 for 12 months - [Month in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43828883/why-is-the-javascript-date-month-index-0-based)

Also check for Java Explaination - [Month in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/344380/why-is-january-month-0-in-java-calendar)

Answer (score 0):

If the use of an external library is possible for you, then I would suggest [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/), like here:

```js
alert("It's the " + moment.utc().format('MM') + ". month of the year " + moment.utc().format('YYYY') + ".")
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.26.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi @Peter thanks, yes it is, I just thing moment is a little too much for just this small thing, I was about to look into date-fns